# Shopify Assets API unexpected constant in blade template

Tags: laravel-5, shopify, shopify-app

I am passing mySnippet in Shopify via assets API then later i want to use the variables passed from include snippet i am getting unexpected constant

Snippet code i put in cart.liquid file

```
{% include 'mySnippet', appKey:'2001' %}
```

My PHP CODE

```
    $mySnipet = view('mySnippet')->render();
```

Blade file

```
{{mapKey}}
```

Error
Unexpected constant mapKey

Answer (score 0):

You can pass liquid variable string in value of key in view then from your snippet you can use it as following

```
{% include 'mySnippet', appKey:'2001' %}
```

PHP CODE

```
    $data = array();
    $data['mapKey'] = "{{mapKey}}";
    $mySnippet = view('mySnippet',$data)->render();
```

Blade Template

```
{{$mapKey}}
```

Final output in template.liquid at Shopify will be following

```
{{mapKey}}
```

Once your snippet render on Shopify page it

```
2001
```